# Convert LaTex to MathML

Tags: javascript, html, latex, mathml

I'm using Mathquill inside NicEdit WYSIWYG editor to get answers for mathematical paper questions.

The clients is requesting to send the answers in MathML. Mathquill currently outputs in LaTex format and I'm getting all the typed text in LaTex with a button click. But I want that to convert it into MathML before sending to the server.

As far as I know MathJax is the easiest to do that. But it does only convert from a DOM element when typing or on page load.

I'm very new to JavaScript and any suggestions to do this would really appreciated.

PS: Better if it is supported on IE 8+ too.

Comment: Refer to [MathToWeb](http://www.mathtoweb.com/cgi-bin/mathtoweb_home.pl)